# Getting HTTP Response Header without text

Tags: http, https, http-headers, httpresponse

I am using HTTPURLConnectionImpl class for HTTP calls, however i am getting different response header format for different URL like below

**HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**    - Has "Not Found" text

**HTTP/1.1 404**              - No text

Why the response header is different for different request URLs ?

Regards,
Sagar

Answer (score 0):

Because the server is free to choose what response text to add (or to leave it out).